# What are the "best" groups to use as examples while learning new concepts in algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question

While learning new concepts in algebra it is quite helpful to check some examples which includes the groups that we are familiar with, like $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $S_n$, $GL(2,\mathbb{R}), \dots$

For example, while learning quotient groups, we can choose a normal subgroup $H=\{\bar{0},\bar{2},\bar{4}\}$ of the group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ to understand *what is going on*.

I know my question seems subjective, but, I think that some of you have the groups that you know well and use them often. So, what groups -or rings, fields-  can you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: This would be more appropriately a question to pose at [Mathematics Educators](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Pretty nearly everything that comes up in intro group theory can be illustrated in $D_8$, the group of symmetries of the square.

Comment: Thank you all. I asked the question to Math Educators SE:
http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/12094/what-are-the-best-groups-to-use-as-examples-while-learning-new-concepts-in-alg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an introduction to groups itself, the **Rubik's Group**, the **Dihedral Groups**, small **permutation groups** are especially useful. Some more interesting examples are the **braid groups**, **isometry groups**, and **automorphism groups** of groups and graphs. **Cyclic Groups** are also a very good example.

As for teaching concepts in group theory, I think small finite groups are the best idea. To build up larger groups, constructing them via products  (and semidirect products) of smaller groups is a good idea.

I am personally a fan of [Visual Group Theory by Nathan Carter](http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/visual-group-theory). This book discusses a large number of group theory concepts using diagrams called Cayley Diagrams, which let's you visualize the group in terms of the relations of their generators.

Comment: Thank you!
By the way, I asked the question to Math Educators SE:
http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/12094/what-are-the-best-groups-to-use-as-examples-while-learning-new-concepts-in-alg